# jQuery highlight effect does not work with Bootstrap's row classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using jQuery and Bootstrap 3 on my site.  I have a table that uses Bootstrap's table-striped class to get different colored rows.  Several of the rows have added the "danger" class from Bootstrap to show the row in red.
I also have several anchors, that jump down to a particular row, and I want that action to have a temporary highlight for the row, so the user knows which row they are jumping to.

If the jumped-to row does not have the "danger" class added, then the highlight works fine, but if the row has the danger class, then the highlight does not happen.

Here's the table (condensed somewhat)

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <tr id="11111-row" class="class1 class2 ">
      <td><a name="11111">blah</td>
      <td><a href="#33333" onclick="flashRow(33333)">33333</a>)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="22222-row" class="class1 class2 ">
      <td><a name="22222">blah</td>
      <td><a href="#44444" onclick="flashRow(44444)">44444</a>)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="33333-row" class="class1 class2 ">
      <td><a name="33333">blah</td>
      <td><a href="#77777" onclick="flashRow(77777)">77777</a>)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="44444-row" class="danger class1 class2 ">
      <td><a name="44444">blah</td>
      <td><a href="#88888" onclick="flashRow(88888)">88888</a>)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here's the flashRow Javascript function:

```
function flashRow(bug_id){
  row = $('#'+bug_id+"-row");
  row.effect( "highlight", {color:"#669966"}, 10000 )  
}
```

When I click on the link in row 11111, it jumps to row 33333, and the row is highlighted correctly.
When I click the link in row 22222, it jumps to row 44444, but since the row has the "danger" class (which makes the row have a red background), I do not see the highlight.

If I use the browser inspector, I can see that in either case, when I click on the effect is still happening, but the bootstrap "danger" class prevents it from working.

How do I get it to work?

https://jsfiddle.net/eyr5ouy9/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is "working" in the sense that the javascript is modifying the style of the danger row, but the danger class is already modifying the background color of that row. It probably has to do with the specificity of the css, and in bootstrap's css I imagine you will find a rather specific group of selectors to get to that danger row, so merely setting the style to background X (which is what the highlight is doing) doesn't suffice to override it.
You could remove the class for the duration of the highlight effect perhaps?
(If you are using Chrome or FF, you can watch the effect "happening" by right clicking the element, going to inspect, and in the elements tab of that console watch what happens on the tr

try this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyr5ouy9/9/)

```
function flashRow(bug_id) {
  row = $('#' + bug_id + "-row");
  var hasDanger = row.hasClass('danger');
  var self = this;
  row.removeClass('danger')
  row.effect("highlight", {
    color: "#669966"
  }, 1000,
  function(){if(hasDanger){row.addClass('danger');}})
}
```

Comment: As I said, I am using the inspector.  What I see is that when I click on the link, the jumped-to row temporarily has an additional "style=background-image:none; background-color: rgb(x,y,z)" attribute that makes the effect happen.  I thought that any "style=" attributes in CSS are supposed to have the highest precedence over any other class-based styles.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I hadn't read very closely. Regrettably I don't know that much about CSS, but the fiddle I have here works (removing the class and adding it back once the animation is complete). Hopefully someone more knowledgable will come along and explain why the style isn't working.

Comment: I would have liked to have a solution that works natively with Bootstrap, but this works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to toggle classes instead jsfiddle.net/dem4hsse/2

Comment: If you really want 10 seconds of animation you can always choose CSS transitions http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: I don't want to toggle the class.  I just want to have a quick flash to show the user which row they went to.  The 10 second animation was only so I could watch what happens during the effect.  The jsfiddle has a 1 second animation.